# Firebase Invite user by email and add to a company

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an React app where each user belongs to a company. The first person in that company is the manager, who can invite other users. They'll get an email link to sign up.

How do I attach the companyId (or another piece of info to connect them) to the invite so that when a new user is invited and authenticated this person is added to the company?

I tought of 2 possible solutions.

1. Adding an invitedEmail array to the company collection and run a cloud function to check if a new users email belongs to the company.
2. Add somewhere the id of the company in the invite and get this id while new user signs up. But don't know where or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 primary collections - companies and users. When the first user joins, create the company document with `companyId` as the doc ID and also user's own document (and store `companyId` as field). Whenever the manager adds a user, you can create another document in users collection with same `companyId` as of the manager, store a status field as "invited" and send a sign in link to user.

You can use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) as shown below:

```
exports.inviteUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const { email } = data;
    const { uid } = context.auth;

    // 1. Find user's companyId using caller's UID
    // 2. Add a document in users collection invited user with their email
    // 3. Generate a sign in link and email to user.
 
    return { message: "User invited" } 
});
```

You can [generate a sign-in link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link) using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). You'll need a third party service to send the link via e-mail. Firebase [Trigger Email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email) extension should make that easier.

Comment: Thank you this helps, but what happens when the invited user signs up? How do you merge the document of the user that the manager created with the newly authenticated user document? (Based on what info)

Comment: @YuvalPappie check the documentation of generating sign in links in my answer. You can pass the new user's doc ID in `ActionCodeSettings`. From the docs, _"ActionCodeSettings allow you to pass additional state via a continue URL which is accessible after the user clicks the email link."_ You can access that info later and use it as per your needs.